# Angular 5's HttpClient: What arguments does toPromise() accept?

Tags: typescript, promise, httpclient, angular5

If I try to return a promise of a specific type like this:

```
public myMethod(): Promise<MyType> {
  return this.httpClient.get('/my/url').toPromise();
}
```

...I get an error that the return type Promise<Object> does not match the expected type Promise<MyType>. That's easy enough to fix by casting the result or by doing this:

```
public myMethod(): Promise<MyType> {
  return this.httpClient.get<MyType>('/my/url').toPromise();
}
```

There's another option, however, to provide an optional argument to the toPromise() function. My IDE says the type of the argument is either "PromiseCtor: PromiseConstructorLike" or "PromiseCtor: typeof Promise".

```
public myMethod(): Promise<MyType> {
  return this.httpClient.get('/my/url').toPromise(???);
}
```

I can't figure out what syntax would satisfy the ??? above, however.

Any ideas about what can be filled in as a valid argument here?

Comment: I think it's asking for the [`Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Which could either be the native one, or one provided by your favourite promise library. This does not help you with `MyType`, btw.

Comment: Assuming you have a special type of promise MyPromise, you would pass that type (i.e. the constructor function of your MyPromise). The goal is not to solve the problem you have. The goal is too return a specific type of Promise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type in the get method `get<MyType>`:

```
public myMethod(): Promise<MyType> {
   return this.httpClient.get<MyType>('/my/url').toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async myMethod(): MyType {
  return await <MyType>this.httpClient.get('/my/url').toPromise();
}
```